# javascript not calculating value with same ID

Tags: javascript, calculated-field

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="description" required /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" onkeyup="sum();" required /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="price" id="price" onkeyup="sum();" required /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lineTotal" id="lineTotal" readonly /></td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="addLine();" value="+" /></td>
</tr>
```

Below is my javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addLine() {
      var tabLines = document.getElementById("tabLines");
      var tabLinesRow = tabLines.insertRow(tabLines.rows.length-1);
      var col1html = "<input type='text' name='description' />";
      var col2html = "<input type='text' name='quantity' id='quantity' onkeyup='sum();' />";
      var col3html = "<input type='text' name='price' id='price' onkeyup='sum();' />";
      var col4html = "<input type='text' name='lineTotal' id='lineTotal' readonly />";
      var col5html = "<input type='button' onclick='removeLine(this);' value='-'>";


      var col1 = tabLinesRow.insertCell(0); col1.innerHTML=col1html;
      var col2 = tabLinesRow.insertCell(1); col2.innerHTML=col2html;
      var col3 = tabLinesRow.insertCell(2); col3.innerHTML=col3html;
      var col4 = tabLinesRow.insertCell(3); col4.innerHTML=col4html;
      var col5 = tabLinesRow.insertCell(4); col5.innerHTML=col5html;
    }

    function removeLine(lineItem) {
      var row = lineItem.parentNode.parentNode;
      row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
    }

    function sum() {
        var q = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
        var p = document.getElementById('price').value;
        var result = parseInt(q) * parseInt(p);

        if(q=="" || p==""){
            document.getElementById('lineTotal').value = 0;
        }

        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('lineTotal').value = result;
        } 
    }

</script>
```

I am trying to do some calculations here. When i calculate the default single row, it does calculate, when i press on add button and i do some calculations in the second row it works, but when i add more rows it does not calculate. I don't know how to solve it. Please help as i a newbie in javascript

Comment: IDs must be unique in HTML. You can use classes instead.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your problem is that you are duplicating ID's

Try adding an index for your ID's for each row added

Answer (score 1):

ID's are something that has to be unique. If you need to refer to elements that are the same, use `class` instead.

Comment: To make it work with this approach, appart from changing all the `id='price'` and `id='quantity'` to `class='price'` and `class'quantity'`, you also have to change your sum() method in order to obtain all the elements with the corresponding class (Check [document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName))

Comment: He wouldn't make his classes all different. that would defeat the purpose. He would use the `document.getElementsByClassName()` as you mentioned but he can index everything from there. This is obviously only one of many ways to accomplish what he's trying to do.

Comment: i would like to know how i can index the id's as i think it would much an easier solution as the getElementsByClassName is not working still

Answer (score 1):

That right there is your problem. The id attribute in an HTML element should be unique in the entire page. However, you could try to add an index as a suffix for each repeated element in your rows, like "quantity1", "price1", etc.

I also suggest trying out the developer tools within your browser, specially the console and the debugger. There you can run your javascript code step by step (debugger) or on demand (console) to check where do you have an error.

Comment: I am getting the quantity1 as indexes. It was working.. But i am still not able to do the calculation